# Cardinality restrictions on SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, restrictions, rdfs, cardinality

My question is about SPARQL query language of RDF triples, suppose we have a family ontology written in RDF/XML format.

Now, I want to query all *parents*, for example, with at least two children (cardinality on `hasChild` relation) with SPARQL.

My question is, is it possible to write this query in SPARQL language, however I know this is possible to write this query in DL query language (Description Logic)

In more general form, Is it possible to apply some cardinality restrictions in SPARQL language?

Comment: "a family ontology written in RDF/XML format"  Do you mean an OWL ontology?  An RDFS "ontology"?  RDF/XML is just one *serialization* format for RDF, but a number of different ontology languages can be encoded in RDF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now, I want to query all parents, for example, with at least two
> children (cardinality on hasChild relation) with SPARQL.

You just select a parent and child in each row, then group by the parent, and then only take those that have at least two values for child:

```sql
select ?parent where {
  ?parent :hasChild ?child
}
group by ?parent
having (count(distinct ?child) >= 2)
```

Beware though; In OWL you can have an individual that must have at least two children, but that this query wouldn't return. E.g., if you have

```
TwoChildParent subClassof (hasChild min 2)
Joe a TwoChildParent
```

but don't have any

```
Joe hasChild ?x
```

triples, this query won't return **Joe**, even though **Joe** has at least two children.

Comment: Thanks Joshua! my ontology is of type OWL and your query worked perfect

Comment: @abforce Beware though;  In OWL you can have an individual that must have at least two children, but that this query wouldn't return.  E.g., if you have `TwoChildParent subClassof (hasChild min 2)` and `Joe a TwoParentChild`, but don't have any `Joe hasChild x` triples, this query won't return Joe, even though Joe has at least two children.

Comment: I might misunderstand, but shouldn't it be `Joe a TwoChildParent` instead of `Joe a TwoParentChild`?

Comment: @BarryNL Good catch! Fixed now.